# How to simulate DOM events in the React components for testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to simulate DOM events for the testing of React components. The component internally  uses ag-grid-react.

I want to simulate row interaction events with ag-grid-react like 'row select', 'row dblclick' and event should be like real DOM event which has all the effect of that event in the DOM.

please suggest any ideas for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would read this article:

http://2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html

Essentially you just want to create a new event with the Event constructor, then use the .dispatchEvent() method on whichever element you want to trigger the event on.

Note: I haven't tried this before but it seems simple enough... Let me know how it goes! Last time I tried something similar I was using jQuery :/